# Convert old ArcGIS 9 VBA tool to new Python script tool for ArcGIS 10

Tags: arcgis-10.0, python, vba, convert

I have an ArcGIS .mxd file with an imbedded VBA script that is executed from a tool bar button. I would like to convert this VBA script tool to a python script tool for use in ArcGIS 10. Is that possible?

Comment: Do you mean automatically convert it? You should be able to manually translate the script without too much difficulty - assuming you know some python.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, with the caveat that it will live in the application and not the MXD. If you create a Geoprocessing script tool in Python with zero parameters, you can add it to any toolbar from the Customize menu and it will execute when you click it. If it has 1 or more parameters, it will bring up the GP tool dialog.